# compiling and linking is not working ubuntu 17.10/clang

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I am unable to link and compile the AWS SDK with the following link error:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ns_api.dir/src/main.cpp.o: undefined 
    reference to symbol '_ZN3Aws4FreeEPv'
    /usr/bin/ld: //deps/aws_sdk/aws-cpp-sdk-core/libaws-cpp-sdk- 
    core.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ns_api.dir/build.make:95: ns_api] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/ns_api.dir/all] 
    Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Additionally, it seems that I need to specify the build directory with `aws-sdk-cpp_DIR` even though I did a `make install` - should this not have placed the lib in the systems lib dir?

---

I installed the package as follows:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DENABLE_TESTING="FALSE" -DBUILD_ONLY="s3" . && make install -j8
```

I am under the impression that this issue should not be present given I following the install instructions exactly within an isolated ubuntu environment

Please advise

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @KenWhite this issue is potentially an internal defect in the AWS SDK and therefore might fall in scope of a new issue

Comment: I see an *undefined reference* error, followed by a *DSO missing from command line*. Don't see any *internal defect* there, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to follow up here with my own answer:

target_link_libraries( ... aws-cpp-sdk-core aws-cpp-sdk-s3 ... )

was required in my cmake file

adding the core lib for the linker was not required in other installations, so this a ton of caused confusion on my end.